# Procedural terrain in the Style of "Zelda: A Link to the Past"

Tags: procedural-generation, tilemap, terrain

I am working to create a system that randomly generates pseudo-3d terrain on a tile grid using the methods used in the legend of zelda games between link to the past and minish cap.

I have created a tileset for it, and after manually making some maps and getting a feel for what the tile placement algorithm needs to do, I've implemented one of four possible layer-transitions. There are still some special edge-cases which will likely need special tiles, but the image shows a fully procedural map using it. My implementation keeps track of the altitude of each vertex (not center) of a tile. By comparing the altitudes at each corner, and in some cases those around the focused tile, I can determine which sprite to use.

This system needs to be "infinite" in that I can generate chunks adjacent to existing ones using the same noise function. I have plans to make a worldmap system similar to a LOD system too, which wouldn't be too hard with perlin noise, but alternative suggestions should keep this in mind.

I have several questions about this system. The first is this: How I can make my noise more like the example, preferring to line up edges which are nearby (but only to a degree)? How can I make it prefer less complex shapes, more similar to octagons than realistic messy hills?

The second is about how I can connect the layers: for altitude changes greater than 1 level, I want to require the player to use ramps. Unfortunately I don't have a solid example of this in my current tileset, but essentially, two disconnected altitudes should have a "slope" (really just the neutral tile) between them... I could use A* or similar, but how do I detect where it needs to be used? Or is there a better way to ensure connectivity?

Excuse the programmer ""art"" please

What I have:
[image: Example of the current terrain]

What I want:
[image: An example of what I want]

Comment: This particular terrain style may be challenging to achieve purely with noise-based approaches. You can get some similar shapes by [changing the distance metric used in your noise function](http://yunzhishi.github.io/voronoi.html) - for Perlin-style noise, this would entail changing the interpolation function. Or potentially running a cellular automaton on the result to transform wiggly segments into straight lines. But it's hard to get good guarantees of large plateaus like the example. This might be a use case for wave function collapse, though that's substantially more complex.

Comment: I appreciate the pointer toward wave function collapse. If I provided the previous chunk's border as required tiles, I could probably make them seamless, but is that the standard "correct" way to do that or is there another way to make infinite output? (I think that might result in asymetry outside the origin?)

Comment: There's no such thing as "correct" — the only question is whether it serves your game's needs. You're building your own custom world, so any and every method that makes the kinds of worlds you want is a valid thing to try.